# How to override all time attributes

Tags: mysql, laravel, datetime, laravel-4

In my model I have functions to set and get time attributes like so

```
  public function setEndTimeAttribute($value)
  {
    return $this->attributes['end_time'] = date("H:i", strtotime($value));
  }
  public function getEndTimeAttribute($value)
  {
    return date("h:i a", strtotime($value));
  }
  public function setStartTimeAttribute($value)
  {
    return $this->attributes['start_time'] = date("H:i", strtotime($value));
  }
  public function getStartTimeAttribute($value)
  {
    return date("h:i a", strtotime($value));
  }
```

I am doing this because MySQL requires the format a certain way and I want to display it to my user in a different format. I will need to do this for all my time inputs.

I can continue to make these get/set functions for each attribute in my model but I am hoping someone can reveal to me a better way where I only need to do it once. Seems to me like I am doing it wrong the way I am doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider taking advantage of the excellent [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) package provided out of the box with laravel

In your model, add any field you want to be returned as a Carbon instance to the `$dates` array:

```
protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'custom_field'];
```

Now when you call your model it will automatically return a Carbon instance and allow you to do things like:

```
// In your controller
...
$user = App\User::find($id);

return view('user', compact('user'));
...

// Then in your view 
<p> Joined {{ $user->created_at->diffForHumans(); }} </p>

// output
Joined 8 days ago
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to group accessor/mutators on multiple fields. Laravel calls them when accessing them, this happens on a per attribute basis either by getting or setting.

If however, you have a lot of these attributes with similar names (start_time, end_time) throughout your models, you might want to consider using a trait. That way you will just have to use the trait in your model and you can keep all your logic in 1 place.

Example:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

trait TimeFieldsTrait
{
    public function formatDisplayTime($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('h:i a');
    }

    public function formatDbTime($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('H:i');
    }

    public function setEndTimeAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['end_time'] = $this->formatDbTime($value);
    }

    public function getEndTimeAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->formatDisplayTime($value);
    }

    public function setStartTimeAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['start_time'] = $this->formatDbTime($value);
    }

    public function getStartTimeAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->formatDisplayTime($value);
    }
}
```

And in your model you would just use that trait...

```
class YourModel extends Model
{
    use TimeFieldsTrait;
}
```